# horizontall custom scroll bar plugin using jquery

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

I need a horizontal custom scroll bar plug in for my project. I want a plug in, which should be open source, which should work in all OS, all browsers, should work in resize, and also should work in mouse wheel, mouse click and mouse drag.

Any one help me? Please! Thanks in advance!

Comment: This site is a way to get answers to technical problems and not to have others google it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I used this one http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/
It is working fine in my projects, it has a lot of options and themes.

Comment: Thanks dmrtrii, I already used this plug in. It have an issue, that it does not working fine in chrome browser in ubuntu OS. So only i'm searching for other